# $f\circ g\circ h$ is one-to-one and $f,~h$ is invertible, then $g$ is also one-to-one

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $h:A\to A,~g:A\to B,~f:B\to B$.

Suppose $f,~h$ is invertible.
 If $f\circ g\circ h$ is one-to-one, then $g$ is also one-to-one.

How to prove this without directly using the definition?
I know there is a theorem that says, if $f\circ g$ is one-to-one, then $g$ is one-to-one. However, I found that it can not be used here, the pattern doesn't match. Is there any theorem that can be directly applied here and get the conclusion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f$ doesn't have to be whatever: if $h$ is invertible and $f\circ g\circ h$ is one-to-one, then $(f\circ g\circ h)\circ h^{-1}=f\circ g$ is too. But it is standard that it the composition of two functions is one-to-one (resp. onto), the first in the order of composition is one-to-one (resp. the second is onto).

This result is proved by contrapositive: if $g$ is not one-to-one, then $f\circ g$ cannot be one-to-one.

Comment: I write down the formal proof to let you check whether I get it right. Since $h$ is invertible, then $h^{-1}$ is one-to-one. Then $(f\circ g\circ h)\circ h^{-1}$ is one-to-one. Thus $f\circ g$ is one-to-one. Then $g$ is one-to-one.

Answer (score 1):

You need the definition of "one-to-one":

Let $a_1,a_2 \in A$ such that $g(a_1)=g(a_2)$. Since $h$ is invertible , there are  $x_1,x_2 \in A$ with $a_1=h(x_1)$ and $a_2=h(x_2)$.

Then we get $(f\circ g\circ h)(x_1)=(f\circ g\circ h)(x_2)$.

$f\circ g\circ h$ is one-to -one implies now: $x_1=x_2$. This gives $a_1=a_2$.